# Spring template MVC project fail to run out of box, STS2.8.1 on linux 64bit

Tags: java, spring

Unable to run spring template project on STS.  Where to check it?

There is a spring template with STS. But, it failed on an old STS, and failed on a freshly installed STS-2.8.1, nothing changed but give a project name and top package to start the project.

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/you/home.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

And it seems all configured in web.xml, and servlet-context.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Can we believe the contextConfigLocation setting must be ok?  Why it can not get the handler?

Comment: please add more information regarding the "failure". an error message could help.

Comment: You provide insufficient information to debug from. Right now, we can see it's not an obviou problem in the config fragment you've provided and that the error message isn't saying very much beyond “can't work out what to do with *blah*”.

Comment: There's no my setting, it supposed to run after STS installation. So I give mt system setting.  It's an out of box installation of STS-2.8.1, on Ubuntu (linux) 11.04, JAVA_HOME set system default: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk.

Comment: STS has two kind of Spring "template" projects. The old one `Spring/Spring Project" and the new onces "SpringSource Tool Suite/Spring Template Project" -- The leater one has 6 Different Templates -- About which one are you complaining? (Spring MVC Project?)

Comment: The one failed to run is:  File -> New -> Spring Template Project -> Spring MVC Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct url for the Home controller is `<server>/<applicationName>/` (not `.../home.html").

So for example it the Projects name is "test" and you use a Tomcat, then the urls is: `http://localhost:8080/test/`

---

And I fond a second problem, but I can not reproduce it

I have tryed the "Spring MVC Template" my own and get stucked with exaxtly the same output.

I was reading the code and configuration again and again, and did not find any mistake, because there is no.

After I modified the `HomeController`

```
public HomeController() {
   logger.info("init home");
}
```

It starts suddenly working! -- So I think it was a Eclipse referesh Problem. (Just try to clean and republish the project)

Comment: First, your answer works amazingly.  I don't know why an constructor is needed. For the correct URL: If you are using STS, just "open ... page" with the tc Server, it will send you to the correct URL.

Comment: I can't help to say, the answer can't be found in textbook, or springframework documents, because all codes are correct and it fails. It works to add the empty argument constructor, it's amazing. Same as adding an space in codes, and delete it to make it compile.

Comment: @Andrew_1510: The constructor is not needed -- it was only a example how to trigger eclipse to update the file, you can remove the constructor after it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:
First stop the server if it is running.
Expand src Tree and 
Select src/main/webapp 
Right click it
From Popup Menu select Build Path
Select 'Use As Source Folder' option
Now try to run the project again